# error, glibc detected

Tags: glibc

here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct numbers_struct {
      char numbers_array[1000];
  };
  char Line[300];
  FILE *Fp;
  int i=0;
  long size;
  Fp=fopen("input2.txt","r");
  fscanf(Fp, "%ld", &size);
  struct numbers_struct *numbers = malloc(sizeof(struct numbers_struct) * size);
  while(!feof(Fp))
    {
      if (fgets(Line,1000,Fp)!=NULL)
        {
          strncpy(numbers[i].numbers_array,Line,1000);
          i++;
        }
    }
  int k;
  k=i;
  for(i=k-1;i>=0;i--)
  printf("%s",numbers[i].numbers_array);
  free(numbers);
  fclose(Fp);

  return 0;
}
```

When I run it, program prints correct output and then this error message:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./part2: double free or corruption (out): 0x08834170 ***
part2: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What did I do wrong?

You have [corrupted heap](http://www.efnetcpp.org/wiki/Heap_Corruption).

The best way to diagnose heap corruption are [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) and [AddressSanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/AddressSanitizer). Either of these should point you directly at the problem.

There are two obvious bugs in your program:

- `fgets(Line,1000,Fp)` -- how big is the `Line`, and how many characters are you reading into it if presented with a long line?
- `struct numbers_struct *numbers = malloc(sizeof(struct numbers_struct) * size);` -- what happens if the input file starts with `3` but contains 15 lines?